# Link HTML page to NodeJS Server - wont load as localhost?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to create a nodejs server - I have previously managed to - without an HTML page. However, for this task I need to have it direct to RedGreenBlue.html. I am really struggling and any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks

JS Server

```
var http = require('http'),
fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('./RedGreenBlue.html', function (err, html) {
  if (err) {
    throw err; 
  }       
  http.createServer(function(request, response) {  
    response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
    response.write(html);  
    response.end();  
  }).listen(8000);
});
```

Comment: Can you describe how what the current behavior is vs. expected behavior? It's not clear if/how your code _isn't_ working for you.

Comment: Sorry - I input 'node ServerRedBlueGreen.js' to the nodejs console and nothing happens, as in no errors occur or anything. When I try to load localhost I just get an error message to say it is refusing to respond.

Comment: This is working for me (provided `RedGreenBlue.html` actually exists). Are you sure it does?

Comment: Yes 'RedGreenBlue.html' definitely exists, it is located in the same folder as the JS server files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't see anything, because there is no output to `stdout` in your application (e.g. no `console.log`). Therefore, when you execute the app via `node ServerRedBlueGreen.js`, it reads the defined file and opens the port 8000. You can communicate with the application through this port via HTTP.

So open up another shell and execute `curl http://localhost:8000` and you should see a response. You could open the URL in your browser as well.

Hope I could help in some way :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this - why should I need 'console.log?' @jacob above has managed to get it working for him.

Comment: No, that was just the explanation regarding your question why the application does not output anything. Your code is working. I think that you missed the port while trying to access the application in your browser. The correct URL is http://localhost:8000

Comment: Maybe there is confused as I didn't mention that 'RedGreenBlue.html' is to be opened in the browser, not the console.

Comment: Ahh excellent, it is working. I thought I could access it via 'localhost', didn't realise it required the port extension too. Many thanks!

Comment: Okay, can you explain your use case in detail? What do you want to achieve exactly? When you start the application via `node ServerRedBlueGreen.js` it will start a HTTP server which responds with the contents of `RedGreenBlue.html`. You have to send a HTTP GET request to the server with the help of a HTTP client (like a browser or `curl`, etc.).

**Edit:** Perfect. Glad I could clarify it :)